# How do i receive additional query parameters with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

My url looks like this.

```
http://www.example.com/fb-ex1.php
http://www.example.com/fb-exg2.php
http://www.example.com/fb-exx3.php
```

Htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^fb-([a-zA-Z0-9-_]+)\.php$ fb.php?query1=$1 [L]
```

Now, When the user logs in, I guess i am not able to receive the code and state variable
How do i change the rewirte rule to receive additional query parameters?

Comment: So your query params before re-write are ex1, exg2, exx3? Could you give an example of your pre-rewrite URL with multiple query params?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of mistakes:

1. hyphen should be at the start or at the end in a character class otherwise it needs to be escaped.
2. Not using QSA (query string append) flag. This flag ensures to preserve existing query parameters while adding new ones.

Your rule should be rewritten to:

```
RewriteRule ^fb-([\w-]+)\.php$ fb.php?query1=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```